# How to store location-based data using Geolocation API (Foursquare/Places)?

Tags: api, web-applications, geolocation

So, I have a web app idea but I'm struggling to understand the interaction that will need to occur between both my server-side database and the geolocation API (e.g. Foursquare/Google Places).

All I need to do is simply store information, like news article(s), for each location-item (e.g. bar, store, park).  How do I store this information in my database so that I can perform the following search:

**Search:**  Display the top places within a 25 miles radius that have more than 10 associated news articles that reside in my database.

**My Solution**:  Pull down all the places within 25 miles from API service, join that list with my database of news articles, and filter for results that have more than 10 news articles?

Not sure how these type of geolocation apps should work?  Any clarification would be great.